# Why aren't I getting Distinct results?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, distinct

Below is my SQL code that I have written, but have come to realize that things are being duplicated which is not acceptable.  I'm not very familiar with SQL and have been having issues with this and would greatly appreciate any help.  Also I have edited this so I know there are extra tables in here, but will this slow down the performance?

```
select distinct
ru.registername AS [1]
,lc.lifecyclename AS [2]
,s.statename AS [3]
,t.timername AS [4]
,t.lastexecuted AS [5]
from hsi.wfsrvrxlcstate wxs with (nolock)
join hsi.registeredusers ru with (nolock) on wxs.registernum = ru.registernum
join hsi.lcstate s with (nolock) on wxs.statenum = s.statenum
join hsi.lcxstate lxs with (nolock) on s.statenum = lxs.statenum
join hsi.lifecycle lc with (nolock) on lxs.lcnum = lc.lcnum
join hsi.lcstatextimer sxt on s.statenum = sxt.statenum
join hsi.lctimer t on sxt.timernum = t.timernum
join hsi.tasklist tl with (nolock) on t.actionnum = tl.tasklistnum
join hsi.tasklistxtask tlxa with (nolock) on tl.tasklistnum = tlxa.tasklistnum
join hsi.action a with (nolock) on tlxa.tasknum = a.actionnum
order by  registername, lastexecuted desc, lifecyclename
```

Thanks for all help in advance!

Comment: `distinct` works for the entire row.  Could you add an example output, and how it does not conform to your expectation?

Comment: are you sure that the values in each of the columns are not distinct?  It looks like `lastexecuted` might be a datetime, those might not be identical for each row.

Comment: You are getting duplicate rows because, at the very least, a registered user has more than one task. If you want one row per user, how do you want to pick which task gets shown?

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to answer your question without seeing all the table's data in question :'(

... but having said that, I usually resort to the following trick if I am stymied by a complicated join that refuses to yield to a DISTINCT statement.

Show all the table's involved fields in the **select** statement. In your case:

```
select distinct wxs.*, ru.*, s.*.....etc
from ... as per your original query
join ... as per your original query
```

Execute the query and monitor all table_name.id columns. The duplicate line plus the orignating table will be easy to spot as its primary key will be displayed twice. You might need to throw in an order by all PKs to make it easier to spot.

This will give you the clue you need to find the missing FK join.

Good luck!

Comment: Throwing a * at the end of your SELECT is the easiest way to figure out which join is causing repeated data (which is usually what requires the DISTINCT in the first place). I love that trick :)

Comment: Ehm, what?. If you add all columns, how is it supposed to help you find the one that has duplicated values on the original query?

Comment: @Lamak You have duplicate **rows**, not columns. Adding all table's columns makes it easier for you to find your missing FK join, which results in your duplicate rows. Often a Distinct is a patch, which shouldn't be needed most of the time if all your tables are joined.

Comment: @Nazar: You are correct it may be easier for some to identify duplicates (and their cause) by seeing the duplicated IDs. But you are wrong that a missing FK is always the issue. Many to many relationships and tables joined but not shown in the results are other possible causes.

Comment: @SqlRyan face palm! select * is much easier than select a.*, b.*, .., z.* :)

Comment: and `DISTINCT` is 99% of the times, *not* the best solution.

Comment: @ypercube I agree with you although generally Databases are usually designed to 3NF, which precludes duplicate relationships. Agreed re DISTINCT :)

Comment: 3NF or not has nothing to do with this issue. `SELECT c.CustomerName, od.product FROM Customer c JOIN Orders o ON o.cid = c.cid JOIN OrderDetails od ON od.oid = o.oid` may show duplicate results while still in 3NF and no join is missing. Because I have ordered the same item more than one times, in different orders.

Comment: Like a CURSOR, and DISTINCT is generally a symptom, not a solution - there are some cases where it's the right solution (just like a cursor is sometimes the best solution to a problem), but I generally see them used to cover up an incomplete join that results in seemingly-duplicated results.